# Caching solution - is adding timestamp or random numbers at the end of file is acceptable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching

I'm looking for a *quick* solution to fix caching issues (especially in Chrome but should include all modern web browsers).

*Is appending timestamp or random numbers at the end of the file as a parameter good enough?*

For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/somefile.js?123456789"></script>
```

where `12345678` is either a timestamp or randomly generated numbers.

In Developer tools, I can see that Chrome is not using local disk cache in this case.

**DISCLAIMER**

I understand there are better (*proper*) ways to solve this.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/119056/7634537

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

Comment: Marked as duplicate. Please close.